# AWS Mobile Analytics Enviornment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-mobile-analytics

I'm implementing AWS Mobile Analytics on an app with two environments, beta and production. It's working well with the auto export configuration S3 + Redshift but I have a doubt about the environment data split.

Should I have another Mobile Analytics with another configuration to auto export to another Redshift? Or should I have one Redshift and the two apps (beta and production) sending data to the same Redshift? In the second case I could detect from which app is the data coming by the package name that is unique.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure of the question you are asking, but if you are simply trying to filter events in Redshift based on app, you can filter based on application_app_id.

Go to your console and select the app id you'd like to see events for (let's call it 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', then in your Redshift Cluster query:

```
Select *
From   awsma.v_event
Where  application_app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using two apps, one for your production app and one for your beta app.
With the data in Amazon Redshift, you can use the application_app_id column to identify your apps different apps. You could also udpate the v_event view to exclude your beta app data and create a new view called v_beta_view to only show your beta app data.

To create a new view that shows events for a specific app you can use the following query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AWSMA.v_beta_event AS select * from AWSMA.event where application_app_id = '<your beta app id here>';
--grant read access to your read-only users
GRANT SELECT on AWSMA.v__beta_event to group eventreaders;
```